# Use websockets (Socket.io) to mirror jquery events over multiple pages of a node web app

Tags: jquery, node.js, dom, express, socket.io

I have a node.js express socket.io app that will display an input box on testurl.com/grab_input.

On that page there is a keyup event that sends the contents of the box to the sever, and it emits the output to an input box on testurl.com/show_result

So if I open testurl.com/grab_input on one monitor and testurl.com/show_result on another and I type in the first one I see the letters being filled in on the other in real time.

I need to create a similar app that grabs input on the one page and displays it on the other page, but for drawing lines using http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/

So on the first page you'd have a div and you'd draw in it, and then on the other page you'd have a div of the same size positioned in the same place and you'd see the lines being drawn.

Could someone offer any advice on the best way to go about this would be?  Just something to Google or something to go on, I honestly have no idea where to even start?  Is there some kind of thing where you can set events to fire on one page to happen on DOM elements on another?  Thanks!

thanks!

Comment: One idea for you is using [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). It uses P2P connection, and seems to fit your requirements. There are some examples using canvas for showing data from other client while drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial for make sketch app:
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/
Than create socket.io script for create socket between users:
For example:
     Server Side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('drawing',function(json){
     socket.broadcast.emit('drawing',{ x: json.x, y:json.y });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

Client Side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('drawing',function(json){
     // HERE WRITE SCRIPT FOR WRITE ON CANVAS
  });
  // HERE IF USER DRAW SOMETHING ON CANVAS (x and y from sketch script)
  socket.emit('drawing',{x:412,y:444});
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: this is a great suggestion, I will most likely go with this!  Thank you!